# Small gap between image and image border on chrome & edge desktop

Tags: html, css, image, sass, border

I am getting some strange behaviour aligning images within a border on Chrome (Version 93.0.4531.2) and Edge (Version 91.0.864.37) on desktop (Windows 10 20H2, macOS Big Sur 11.3.1). This is not an issue on mobile.

Please refer to the images to see the small gaps. It is very temperamental, since on some cards these appear on the left side, on others on the top, on some on both and on others not at all.

[image: left image has gap at top, middle has gap on left side and top, right has gap at top]

So far I have tried (in various permuatations):

- `margin: 0`
- `padding: 0`
- `display: block`
- `vertical-align: bottom`
- `vertical-align: top`
- `vertical align: -webkit-baseline-middle`

My zoom is set to 100%. Here is the code for my most recent attempt. I am using Vuejs for this project.

vue template:

```html
<div class="card">
  <img v-if="image" :src="image" :alt="name" />
</div>
```

base.scss

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

component scss:

```css
.card {
  width: 240px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  img {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle;
    object-fit: cover;
    border: 1.5px solid black;
  }
}
```

See the behaviour live here: https://www.sableradio.live/shows. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this by simpley remove float number from border css property like this  for reff. attaching image screenshot

```
 .card {
  width: 240px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  img {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle;
    object-fit: cover;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. Unfortunately this does not solve the issue for me - see screenshot [here](https://imgur.com/a/Uy457PV) - also I'd like to keep the border at 1.5px.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue recently.

Although I cannot figure out the root of the problem, I discovered some tricks which you may consider:

1. setting a background to container, let the bg-color blend into the gap

```
.card {
  background-color: black;
}
```

OR

2. negative margin to your photo

```
img {
  margin: -1px;
}
```

Not pretty, but it works for me.

Comment: thanks for writing back Dave, been away from this project for a little while now but when I get back to it will try your suggestions. Half pixels are fiddly, I'll be trying alternatives (i.e. avoiding them!) in the future where possible. Cheers!